# Search / Filter problems

Tags: database, ms-access, search, filter

I have a database that stores a range of email addresses, i also have a table consisting of all of the approved addresses. the search i am looking to complete is one where when i run the approved member query and its returns all of the members that have an email address already approved by the database. i have set up a provider column this i though would be best to link these through for example:

if i have hotmail.com and aol.com authorised

when i run the query it will return all emails ending with these providers. a basic filter could work but i have hundreds of approved emails. so im asking is there anyway to search through the entire column of the approved list?

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
SELECT Email FROM Table 
WHERE Email IN (Select Email FROM ApprovedTable)
```